# Firebase push notifications & GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience#receive_and_handle_notifications) 
for implementing the FCM and every thing is great.

I have a problem when the app on the background the notification is being shown without any control from my side. There is nothing called from my app and I use the GCM in couple of libraries in my app and it can't be replaced. The problem in this case that the gcm is showing a notification and the fcm is showing another one.